# Want to input "#" using IDLE

Tags: python-3.x, encoding, python-idle

I'm using IDLE and for the script I'm writing I need to be able to input #. Using IDLE to execute the code, the # appears red even as input, as it does when used to wrote comments. How can this be worked around? I'm not too versed in the various encodings and such, looking to find a way to make it work with IDLE.

Comment: Did you try putting it in a string literal?

Comment: as in writing '#'? or do you mean str(#)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just enter the string you want to enter.  No 'workaround' is needed.  It is a minor [bug](https://bugs.python.org/issue19808) that IDLE applies syntax coloring to input responses, but is it harmless other than the distraction.

```
>>> s = input(': ')
: #@%!#     
>>> s
'#@%!#'
```

Comment: Thanks so much, the color had me distracted thinking it wouldn't be accepted as a string. As you say it works just fine. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Python IDLE are you using? The below code was written in the Python 3.5.2 IDLE

```
>>> # declare the user input and assign a placeholder variable
>>> user_input = ' '
>>> while user_input != 'end':
    # get user input until the user input the word end
    user_input = input('>> ')
    # as long as the word end is not entered print the input results
    if user_input != 'end':
      print(user_input)
```

Produces the following output:

```
>> #
#
>> ##
##
>> What is the #
What is the #
>> What format would you like the time in ##:##:##
What format would you like the time in ##:##:##
>> Print some ######
Print some ######
>> end
>>>
```

Hope that helps.